# Add Camera permissions when using cordova-plugin-camera in Phonegap hybrid app

Tags: android, phonegap

We are developing a hybrid app using Phonegap cli. The app uses **cordova-camera-plugin** to capture photos. But when we build apk using Phonegap cli, there are no camera permissions added to **androidManifest.xml**.Can someone please guide how to add camera permissions in latest version of **Phonegap**?